# DC-DC Voltage Doubler

Tags: voltage, current

I am an amateur, but i'd like to know if this circuit would work to double a 0-30 volt DC input to a 2-60 volt DC output. If so, what kind of CAPS and DIODES do i need to support this? I need to Power a motor that draws 5A max, so based on my understanding, the circuit needs to be able to handle 10 Amps.

[image]
<sub>(source: [coolcircuit.com](http://www.coolcircuit.com/circuit/voltage/vd.GIF))</sub>

Whatever my input voltage is, I want to double it. I am open to other solutions as well.

Comment: That voltage doubler circuit will only work with an AC input.

Comment: If you just put an H-bridge before this circuit, that may give you the AC that you need to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points:
1) I guess what you are trying to design here is a boost converter. While it is often called a DC/DC converter, the conversion itself is AC/AC. Basically, you create a square wave out of the DC voltage and then upconvert and rectify it afterwards. Almost no one designs those from scratch. If you need a simple voltage doubler, I would get a chip from Digi-Key:
http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/integrated-circuits-ics/pmic-voltage-regulators-dc-dc-switching-regulators/2556570

2) you mention a current spec (5A/10A) for the motor, it is not clear from your post how it is related to the higher voltage you are trying to create here.

Comment: The motor is rated max 90v 5 amps. I have a motor driver that delivers 30v max. The motor is running too slowly...I need to up the voltage...proportional to the input voltage

Comment: You will need a larger motor driver, especially if you want speed control to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit you have drawn is an **AC** voltage doubler. It will **only** work with an AC input.

You feed it `X` volts AC, and you get `2X` DC volts out.

Answer (score -1):

make simple flip flop than doubler with your circuit picture. Or simple doubler voltage you can use joule thief , it will need small transformer.

Comment: Sorry, that is not a valid answer.